# Pass checked items to python using JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, ajax

I am trying to pass checked items to my python code in JSON using an ajax request. The checkboxes are defined in the forms.py file as:

```
NOTES_OPTIONS = (
    ('0', 'Please add 15% VAT'),
    ('1', 'Price is valid for 45 days'),
    ('2', 'All price is in Ethiopian Birr'),
    ('3', 'Delivery will be within 45 days after PO, advance and bank foreign currency approval'),
    ('4', 'Payment Term 50% advance and remaining amount after delivery'),
    ('5', 'Installation is NOT part of this Quote'),
    ('6', 'If there is discrepancy in price calculation the unit price will prevail')
)
note_choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required = False, widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}), choices = NOTES_OPTIONS)
```

and in my create_proposal.html file I have rendered this form as:

```
<div class="row col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="margin-left: 10vw;">
        <div class="container"style="margin-bottom: 20vw;">
            <label><Strong>Choose notes to be included:</Strong></label>
                <ul>
                    {{form.note_choices}}
                </ul>
        </div><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a script in which I accept the values from the form inputs and pass them to my merge.py file:

```
generalData = {
            'file_name': document.getElementById('id_file_name').value,
            'organization_name': document.getElementById('id_organization_name').value,
            'project_type': document.getElementById('id_project_type').value,
            'reference_number': document.getElementById('id_reference_number').value,
            'our_reference_number': document.getElementById('id_our_reference_number').value,
            'date': document.getElementById('id_date').value,
            'exchange_rate': document.getElementById('id_exchange_rate').value,
            'notes': document.getElementById('id_notes').value, 
            'vat': document.getElementById('id_note_choices').value,               
        }
$.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/result/',
            data : { 'values': JSON.stringify(dataJson),
                     'general': JSON.stringify(generalData)
        },
            method: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){
                Download(document.getElementById('id_file_name').value);
                alert(data);

            },
            error: function(data) { 
                alert("something went wrong");

            }
        });
```

the url '/ajax/result/' redirects to the resultPage.
And in my views.py:

```
def resultPage(request):

    jsonData = request.GET.get('values')
    generalData = request.GET.get('general')
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonData)
    generalData = json.loads(generalData)

    merge(jsonData, generalData)
    return JsonResponse("Document written successfully", safe=False)
```

As you see in the script I am trying to pass the checkboxes in the JSON as vat and in my merge.py file I tried to  print it's value as:

```
    print(generalData['vat'])
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
    print(generalData['vat'])
KeyError: 'vat'
```

but when I `print(generalData)` it gives me:

```
{'file_name': '', 'organization_name': '', 'project_type': '', 'reference_number': '', 'our_reference_number': '', 'date': '02/17/2020', 'exchange_rate': '0', 'notes': ''}
```

I also have tried to pass each individual checkbox as:

```
'vat': document.getElementById('id_note_choices_0').value,
```

But this also returns 0 whether it is checked or not.
I want to pass different values when each checkbox is clicked. Any solution is appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Look at your `request.POST` in your view. Or show us your view, it's not clear what is `generalData`.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have edited my code to show you my view

Comment: What does `generalData` contain? Did you try printing it?

Comment: @dirkgroten generalData is a JSON that contains the key value pairs specified and the script. And I retrieved all the data except the one with the vat key

Comment: Show us the output of print

Comment: @dirkgroten I have added the output. As you see the vat key is not even included

Comment: Look at the HTML of your multiple choice widget. You should use `$('input[name=note_choices]:checked')` to fetch all the checked elements, then create an array of the values (you can use the `map()` function for that). There isn't an element with id `id_note_choices`.

Comment: Note that instead of submitting the data as json, it would be easier to just get the `FormData` from your form and pass that as `data` to your ajax call. That way your `request.POST` would just contained the normal submitted form key/values